# Substitute host string in reverse-proxied Location header

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am running a reverse proxy with the following configuration:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name proxy1.mydomain.net;

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://page1.host.com/;
    proxy_redirect https://page1.host.com/ https://proxy1.mydomain.com/;
    proxy_redirect https://page2.host.com/ https://proxy2.mydomain.com/;
    sub_filter 'page1.host.com' 'proxy1.mydomain.net';
    sub_filter 'page2.host.com' 'proxy2.mydomain.net';
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name proxy2.mydomain.net;

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://page2.host.com/;
    proxy_redirect https://page1.host.com/ https://proxy1.mydomain.com/;
    proxy_redirect https://page2.host.com/ https://proxy2.mydomain.com/;
    sub_filter 'page1.host.com' 'proxy1.mydomain.net';
    sub_filter 'page2.host.com' 'proxy2.mydomain.net';
  }
}
```

This seems to be correctly overwriting absolute links, but I can't get 302s between page1 and page2 to work.
For example, loading `https://proxy1.mydomain.net/login` returns

```
HTTP/2 302
server: nginx
location: https://page2.host.com/loginprocess
```

Is there a way to rewrite the `location: https://page2.host.com/loginprocess` to `location: https://proxy2.mydomain.net/loginprocess`?

Comment: The [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) directive is used to alter the `Location` response header.

Comment: Would you mind giving an example? I tried putting `proxy_redirect 'page1.host.com' 'proxy1.mydomain.net'` and `proxy_redirect 'page2.host.com' 'proxy2.mydomain.net'` under both blocks, with no success.

Comment: You have the string you need to match in your question. Try: `proxy_redirect https://page1.host.com/ https://proxy1.mydomain.com/;` and `proxy_redirect https://page2.host.com/ https://proxy2.mydomain.com/;`

Comment: With these in place, I can now get correct redirects within page1, but not from page1 to page2. I'll add them to the question.